# SWFUpload with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swfupload

Hey. I try to use SWFUpload Javascript/Flash library for uploading files in my Rails (RoR) app. Upload works with standard form  but with SWFUpload I get "HTTP Status: 422" error code. Can someone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Does your file get uploaded using swfupload?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up swfupload with rails is not 100% straigtforward. Try looking at this article: [SWFUpload, Paperclip and Ruby on Rails](http://jimneath.org/2008/05/15/swfupload-paperclip-and-ruby-on-rails/)